# Call a method on a class whose instance is owned by another

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, methods, composition

I have two classes, both inherited from `NSObject`. One is called `class1`, the other is called `class2`. They both each have one instance, `class1`->`obj1`, and `class2`->`obj2`.

In `class1`'s `init` method, I make the instance of `class2`. From `obj2`'s `init` method I want to call the instance method `-(void)methode` from `obj1`

How do I do this (what are **delegates**, could I use one)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- initWithThingy:(Class1 *)anObj
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        obj1 = [anObj retain]; // or use your set method/property, if you have one
        [obj1 methode];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: If `obj1` owns `obj2` (as I would assume because `obj1` created/is creating `obj2`), this is a mutual ownership, which may lead to a leak (more precisely, to borrow your term, abandoned objects). It's probably better to have `obj2` just know about `obj1` through a weak/non-retaining relationship.